# Why does my while loop keep asking for input after I added a break?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have an assignment for a class to create a piece of code that will allow the user to input words and it will return the words that contain an 'i' or an 'a'.  However, if the user inputs "Exit", the program will stop.  Mine just keeps asking for input, even though the break should have stopped it.

```
wordprintA = [0]
wordprintI = [0]
dontprint = [0]
while True:
wordlist = [input("Enter a word:").upper()]

for char in wordlist:
    if char == 'A':
       wordprintA.append(wordlist)

for char in wordlist:
    if char == 'I':
       wordprintI.append(wordlist)

else:
      dontprint.append(wordlist)

for char in wordlist:
    if char == 'EXIT':
       break
print(wordprintA, wordprintI)
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Could you ensure correct indention?  That is important with Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break is taking you out of the for loop not the while loop.  You either need to change your while loop to check a variable tied to the char exit or have a second check out of the for loop.  See the below example

```
check=true
while check==true:
   wordlist = [input("Enter a word:").upper()]

   for char in wordlist:
      if char == 'A':
         wordprintA.append(wordlist)

   for char in wordlist:
      if char == 'I':
         wordprintI.append(wordlist)

      else:
         dontprint.append(wordlist)

   for char in wordlist:
      if char == 'EXIT':
         check=false
         break
   print(wordprintA, wordprintI)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Also if this answer solves your problem be sure to check this as the solution so people who have a similar problem in the future know that this is a correct solution